# List in where clause in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello I am a beginner in ASP.NET

I have a variable `checklistsss` which was the list of my CheckList. here is the code:

`var checkListss = (from u in _userManager.ClearanceCheckListRepository.GetQueryable().Where(x => x.ClearanceId == userId.ClearanceId) select new { clearanceCheckListId = u.ClearanceCheckListId }).ToList();`

Now, I want the variable `checkListss` will put in the where clause at this code:

`var due  = from checkListsddd in _userManager.DueRepository.GetQueryable().Where(x => x.ClearanceCheckListId == checkListss) select new { Item = checkListsddd.Label, Action = checkListsddd.Action };`

to output the `due` variable in this code
`var checkList = from checkLists in _userManager.ClearanceCheckListRepository.GetQueryable().Where(x => x.ClearanceId == userId.ClearanceId) select new { ClearanceSignatoryId = checkLists.ClearanceSignatoryId, ClearanceCheckListId = checkLists.ClearanceCheckListId, Item = checkLists.Item, Action = checkLists.Action, Due = due };`

take note that the `checkListss` will output multiple checkListId

I dont know how to do this in asp.net

thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Without some more details I can only guess at the types but I think what you are missing is using [Enumerable.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) to check if the ID is in `checkListss`. Something like:

```cs
var checkListss = (from u in _userManager.ClearanceCheckListRepository.GetQueryable().Where(x => x.ClearanceId == userId.ClearanceId) select u.ClearanceCheckListId).ToList();

var due  = from checkListsddd in _userManager.DueRepository.GetQueryable().Where(x => checkListss.Contains(x.ClearanceCheckListId)) select new { Item = checkListsddd.Label, Action = checkListsddd.Action };
```

Note that I changed `checkListss` to be a list of the Id type instead of a list of an anonymous type.

As a side note the mixing of the LINQ fluent and query syntax is a bit confusing to look at (subjectively) so I would stick to the fluent syntax more like:

```cs
var checkListss = _userManager.ClearanceCheckListRepository.GetQueryable()
    .Where(x => x.ClearanceId == userId.ClearanceId)
    .Select(x => ClearanceCheckListId)
    .ToList();

var due = _userManager.DueRepository.GetQueryable()
    .Where(x => checkListss.Contains(x.ClearanceCheckListId))
    .Select(x => new { Item = x.Label, Action = x.Action })
    .ToList();
```